# JS Object odd behavior

Tags: javascript, html, function, object, phaser-framework

I am currently building a attempting to build a Multiplayer game with Phaser and Eureca io. I am at the stage where i am trying to nail the authentication of the players and what they are controlling, i am doing this by on the server having a method that returns the correct player id.

The method on the server is -

```
 eurecaServer.exports.getPlayer2Id = function(name , id)
 {

   if(name == "Fly" && id == player2id)
   {
     console.log("correct fly player");
     return player2id;
   }
   else
   {
     console.log("Wrong fly player");
     return id;
   }
}
```

On the client side at the moment i am only testing, but when i call the function it returns an object. When simply looking at the object in the console it displays this.
          `Object {status: 0, result: null, error: null, sig: "eY0IjunQt7"}`
so it is telling me my result is null which is odd, but when expanding it i get.

`Object {status: 0, result: null, error: null, sig: "eY0IjunQt7"}
callback: function() 
error: null
errorCallback: function()
onReady: (fn, errorFn)
result: "jVcZvzetc8AAK45NAAAH"
sig: "eY0IjunQt7"`

As you can see when expanding the result is not null, and is exactly what im looking for, i have tried, JSON.stringify but it gives me the first result, where it tells me the result is null.

Any ideas how i can get my actual result or why this is happening.

Thanks.

Edit:

The client side component for server is defined in the main game file

```
var eurecaClientSetup = function() {

var eurecaClient = new Eureca.Client();

eurecaClient.ready(function (proxy) {
    eurecaServer = proxy;

});
```

Then in the object class it is called here.

```
this.name = "Fly"
this.id = index;  //Passed in on object creation
this.currPlayer = eurecaServer.getPlayer2Id(this.name, this.id);
console.log(JSON.stringify(this.currPlayer));
console.log(this.currPlayer);
```

Comment: Where's the code with which the client communicates with the server? If there's a problem, that's a likely place for it to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any server operation is going to be asynchronous, regardless of the framework*. Different frameworks have different ways of getting the result once it is available. In Eureca.io, it seems to be using an `.onReady()` call after the server function name.

In other words, what you need to do is change your client code to the following:

```
this.name = "Fly"
this.id = index;  //Passed in on object creation
var _this = this; // needed because "this" inside function below won't be the same
eurecaServer.getPlayer2Id(this.name, this.id).onReady(function (id) {
    _this.currPlayer = id;
    console.log(_this.currPlayer); // shows the right thing
    // do other stuff here now you have the right player id
});
```

---

<sup>* Technically, you can do a synchronous/blocking AJAX request, but it is bad practice in 99% of cases.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

I'm the author of eureca.io, the answer given by GregL is correct.
I just want to add that onReady() call will be deprecated, eureca.io support promise like call (using then() function).

so you can use this syntax instead, which is more standard.

```
this.name = "Fly"
this.id = index;  //Passed in on object creation
var _this = this; // needed because "this" inside function below won't be the same
eurecaServer.getPlayer2Id(this.name, this.id).then(function (id) {
    _this.currPlayer = id;
    console.log(_this.currPlayer); // shows the right thing
    // do other stuff here now you have the right player id
});
```